# Is there a Python API for the custom property presets in Render Properties?

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I know that I can change render settings with e.g. `C.scene.render.resolution_x`, but I have the values I want stored in one of these:

[image]

I don't know what they're called, I'd call them something like "custom property presets" but it seems like those words have different meanings in the Python API.

I know they're not in the .blend file themselves, so I assume there's some way to read them from the API that handles system-wide preferences. I'm looking to be able to do something like:

```py
C.scene.render.resolution_x = C.preferences.output.format.presets['HDTV 1080p'].resolution_x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DNR: You cant use them that way.  But look at `blender/presets.py` to see how you could use them.

[Using Blender's presets in Python](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-blenders-presets-in-python/) is a tutorial that goes into details on how you can use presets for your own add-ons.

You are correct that the presets are separate from the Blend file.  Each preset is stored with the add-on in its own python file.  In the case of the UI, the presets are stored with the UI code, in the directory where you installed blender in the `scripts/startup/scripts/presets` directory.  The specific presets you are looking for are in the `render` subdirectory.  Here's an example, taken from HDTV_1080p.py:

```py
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 1080
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
bpy.context.scene.render.pixel_aspect_x = 1
bpy.context.scene.render.pixel_aspect_y = 1
bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 24
bpy.context.scene.render.fps_base = 1
```

As you can see, the preset file is a collection of assignment statements.

To access a preset, you would need to read in and execute the python file of the same name.  The code from the Blender UI that does this can be found [here](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/presets.py#L231).

Comment: Oh well this works too! Since the presets are just a Python script I should be able to run them with `--python` on the command line. Thanks for the pointer!